# Adding different values together from same table

Tags: php, sql

I have a table. In that table, there is are two fields called `to` and `amount`. I need to display the sum of `amount` of all rows where `to` value is equal to a particular value. (Say 34). How to achieve this?

Code I have done so far

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE to = '34'")or die(mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) { echo $row['amount']; } ?>
```

The above code gives the individual `amount` value of each row. But what I want is the sum of these values.

[The Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtLyd.png)

Comment: `SELECT SUM(column_name) AS Total FROM table_name;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUM to add all the amounts and echo it

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amount) as amounts FROM transactions WHERE to = '34'")or die(mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) { echo $row['amounts']; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` because `mysql_*` is deprecated and not available in **PHP 7**.

Here is the complete example of your code by using `MYSQLi Object Oriented`:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT SUM(amount) as amounts FROM transactions WHERE to = 34";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['amounts']. "<br>";
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```